# Why isn't my label hiding?

Tags: ios, uistackview

I have a tableViewCell with a stackView. I'm trying to make it a collapsable cell. I can successfully set the hidden state of the 2nd label during tableView:cellForRowAt:

However if I change the hidden state in response to a tap of the cell, visibility doesn't change on-screen.

```
UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.25) { [unowned self] in
    self.disclaimers.isHidden = !cellItem.isExpanded
}
```

The cellItem.isExpanded property is toggled properly as is the label .isHidden property. Just no change on-screen.

I know this is already on the main thread as tableView:didSelectRowAt: is called on the main thread. But to cover myself I tried wrapping the line with a DispatchQueue.main.async { } call instead of the UIView.animate. No change.

Any ideas?

Full project is here if you're willing:  https://github.com/AaronBratcher/TableViewTester

Issue is in DisclaimersCell.swift. Line 33

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Couple issues...

You should never call `.dequeueReusableCell` anywhere other than in `cellForRowAt`. You do that in `TableViewController.swift` -> `didSelectRowAt` ... which creates a *new* instance of the cell, *not* the existing instance in your table. Change your `guard` line to:

```
    guard var cellItem = helper.cellForRowAtIndexPath(indexPath) as? TableViewExpandableCellItem
        , let cell = tableView.cellForRow(at: indexPath) as? TableViewExpandableCell
        , cellItem.shouldExpand
        else { return }
```

That way, `tableView.cellForRow(at: indexPath)` will return the *existing* cell.

Next, animating the setting of `.isHidden` won't give you the animation you want.

In `DisclaimersCell.swift` -> `toggleExpansion()`, change:

```
    UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.25) { [unowned self] in
        self.disclaimers.isHidden = !cellItem.isExpanded
    }
```

to simply:

```
    self.disclaimers.isHidden = !cellItem.isExpanded
```

Then, in your TableViewController `didSelectRowAt` function:

```
    cellItem.isExpanded = !cellItem.isExpanded
    cell.toggleExpansion(tableViewCellItem: cellItem)

    tableView.beginUpdates()
    tableView.endUpdates()
```

That will tell the cell to hide/show the label, and pairing `.beginUpdates()` with `endUpdates()` will trigger the recalculation of row heights in your table, and animate the redraw.